# Read gradle paths from project

Tags: groovy, gradle

Is there any way to access Gradle groovy plugin sourceSets dirs from my Groovy project built by Gradle? I am looking for default gradle src and resources directories.

I need it to avoid hardcoding a resources directory in my project but use the default Groovy plugin resource directory (resources/main).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mix up your production code with your test sources and your test resources. I would suggest the following layout (the default of the groovy plugin) of your src directories in your project:

- groovy production code in "src/main/groovy"
- unit tests written in java or groovy in "src/test/groovy"
  *.groovy resources for testing your DSL in "src/test/resources"

Now you can reference the .groovy dsl test files from your tests via

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/testDsl.groovy");
File testDslFile = new File(url.getFile());
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain the use case for that? within your gradle build you can access the groovy sourceSets dirs introduced by Gradles groovy plugin like this:

```
apply plugin:'groovy'

task printGroovySourceDirs << {
    sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs.each{
        println it.absolutePath
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am actually interested in reading this property (particularly "resources/main") from the built project itself, do you know if it possible? (I have gradle-core and gradle-plugins jars in the project classpath)

Comment: This is not possible at the moment (in a reasonable amount of work). I'm still interested in your usecase! Why does your project need to know at runtime where its sources (in your case the resource sources) are located?

Comment: I develop a Groovy DSL and its integration tests read .groovy files located in a src folder, so path to "src/test/groovy" will work for me as well. Can I somehow parse my build.gradle and fetch this path from the build script or at least get the default one? (maybe using GroovyDefaultSourceSet?)

Comment: Still not sure, that I understand what you try to do, but here's another idea: You can generate/preprocess a groovy class in your build process and put it along with the other sources of your project. During preprocessing/generating this class, you wire the list of directories into this groovy class. Now you can use this class from your application code to refer the resources source folders.